# Disabling Echo Cancellation in WebRTC SDP

Tags: node.js, webrtc, sdp

Is it possible for me to set `noisesuppression=false; echocancellation=false` in the WebRTC SDP? I know I can also do it through the `GetUserMedia` request, but it seems to only use those settings under ideal circumstances.

For example:

```js
 answer.sdp = answer.sdp.replace('useinbandfec=1', 'cbr=1; maxaveragebitrate=510000; noisesuppression=false; echocancellation=false');
```

would that work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you are modifying is for the opus codec which does not have parameters for noise suppression or echo cancellation, see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7587#section-6.1) for a list of parameters.

You can not put random stuff in the SDP.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah, I didn't actually include that line in my code, I was just trying to give an example. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, *is* it possible to add echo cancellation in a line in the SDP?